# How to populate Bootstrap layout with Mysql-data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code, that outputs data from my database:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['cell_phone_name'];
}
```

And here's a Bootstrap layout:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>A place for cell_phone_name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>A place for cell_phone_name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>A place for cell_phone_name</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>A place for cell_phone_name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>A place for cell_phone_name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>A place for cell_phone_name</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've found a code:

```
echo '<div class="container">';

for($i = 1; $i < count($array) + 1; $i++) {
  if(is_int(($i - 1) / 3) || ($i - 1) == 0) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
  }
  echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
  echo '<h2>' . $array[$i]['cell_phone_name'] . '</h2>';
  echo '</div>';
  if(is_int($i / 3)) {
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
echo '</div>';
```

But an array is used here. How should I output my data correctly?

I added code from answers below and corrected it a little bit. Now this works:

```
echo '<div class="container">';
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  if(is_int(($i - 1) / 3) || ($i - 1) == 0) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
  }
  echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
  echo '<h2>' . $row['cell_phone_name'] . '</h2>';
  echo '</div>';
  if(is_int($i / 3)) {
    echo '</div>';
  }
  $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop like this :

```
echo '<div class="container">';
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(is_int(($i - 1) / 3) || ($i - 1) == 0) {
        echo '<div class="row">';
}
echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
echo '<h2>' . $row['cell_phone_name'] . '</h2>';
echo '</div>';
if(is_int($i / 3)) {
    echo '</div>';
}
$i++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried fetch_assoc, but your variant works better!

Comment: But there's one thing: first item is not displaying on a page). I guess the reason is mysqli_fetch_array($result) before cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what I was doing in this situation is to divide the `$result` array to 2, like this:

```
$howMuchChunks = 2;
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$divideAt = round(count($result) / $howMuchChunks);
$arrays = array_chunk($result, $divideAt);
```

Then I loop throw all

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < $howMuchChunks; $i++) {
     while($row = $arrays[$i]) {
         ?>
              <div class="row">;
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                       <h2>  <?php echo $array[$i]['cell_phone_name'] ?> </h2>
                   </div> 
              </div>
         <?php 
     }
}
?>
```

Now the bigest advantge is you can use this chunck again and agian, and you can just change the number of the `$howMuchChunks` for responsive or maybe you want to change it after some time